# Nginx: Response handling and Reverse Proxy with Cache

Tags: nginx, lua

I am running Nginx as an simple Reverse Proxy cum cache and now I want to set some headers based on the response received(body not header).

It looked simple to get the location_capture_by Lua do that but seems I cant get the caching working properly.

Initial set up was :

```
location / {
..
try_files $uri @upstream_server
}

location @upstream_server {
      proxy_pass "http://web_lb";
      proxy_cache small;
      proxy_cache_methods POST;
      proxy_cache_key "$request_uri|$request_body";
      client_max_body_size 500M;
      add_header X-Cached $upstream_cache_status;
      set_real_ip_from   10.86.102.0/24;
      real_ip_header      X-Forwarded-For;
      proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
      proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
}
```

changed it to :

---

```
location /{
 content_by_lua '
     local res = ngx.location.capture(
                "/new-location",
                { method = ngx.HTTP_POST, body = ngx.var.request_body})
     #update response body here and header etc based on content
      ngx.say(res.body)
      '; }

location new-location{
try_files $uri @upstream_server
}

location @upstream_server {
      proxy_pass "http://web_lb;"
      proxy_cache small;
      proxy_cache_methods POST;
      proxy_cache_key "$request_uri|$request_body";
      client_max_body_size 500M;
      add_header X-Cached $upstream_cache_status;
      set_real_ip_from   10.86.102.0/24;
      real_ip_header      X-Forwarded-For;
      proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
      proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
}
```

======

To what I found that I have lost all the original headers an header added as part of Proxy_Header handling including the upstream_cache_status header. However I found that Nginx still serves repeat requests from the cache itself.

Any reason why it would be so? also I am a bit of early starter here, so excuse for some basic gotchas.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, location.capture is not designed to do things you doing, but, if I get you correct (you want to send headers that browser send you to subrequest) you, probably, can hack it around using ngx.ctx + set ;)

But I'd say it is a very dirty kludgy way.